# How to hide the Row per page field along with dropdown from MUI table pagination

Tags: material-ui, hide

As i am new to Material UI react js. I have a doubt to hide rowsPerPage field only page number to be displayed with forward and back arrows

Comment: Can you tell more details about the doubts, like what you tried and how it failed, whether you got errors or what you observed as opposed to what you had expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set an empty array on  `rowsPerPageOptions` to hide it, checkout this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-beaver-jw08yi) ,
more info about it on [tablePagination API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/#props).
alternatively you can use [DataGrid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#data-table)